# Virtualbox + openSUSE 11.2 - how to set up mouse & keyboard?

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse

I installed openSUSE 11.2 in VirtualBox 3.1.2 (the latest one). It bootes ok but mouse and keyboard don't react. Is there a way how to make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they USB? Try installing guest additions ( **Devices -> Install Guest Additions** ).

Comment: First, I tried to control the mouse via touchpad and then I tried to connect USB mouse and neither worked. Mouse pointer is still in the middle of screen. Devices->Install Guest Additions does nothing - I see no dialog window or anything. What should it do?

Comment: Do you have an X Server installed?

Comment: X server is gui, isn't it? I have.

Comment: Check out http://www.susegeek.com/virtualization/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-for-opensuse-guest-os/

Comment: I give it up. Because I wasn't able to connect to the intenet and I couldn't even mount ISO image of openSUSE. I'll try a lower version of openSUSE, maybe there'll be less problems.

Comment: I installed openSUSE 11.1 and everything is working well.

Comment: Excellent news. Didn't need guest additions?

Comment: I haven't installed it yet. It works superb without it, but I guess it will be more comfortable with them (mouse integration).